# Python 'dict' object has no attribute 'status'

Tags: python

I'm currently writing up a Discord bot in Python and am building an `ip info` command. However, when I try to run it, it shows this error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'status'
```

This is my current python code:

```
import discord
import datetime
import pymysql
import time
from datetime import timedelta, timezone
import asyncio
import re
import os
import requests
import json

if message.content.startswith('!ipinfo'):
    input = message.content.replace('!ipinfo', '').strip()

    try:
        req = requests.get('http://ip-api.com/json/{}'.format(input))
        resp = json.loads(req.content.decode())

        if resp.status.code == 200:
            if resp['status'] == 'success':
                # valid ip
                await channel.send(content='IP Logging Here.')
            elif resp['status'] == 'fail':
                await channel.send(content='API Request Failed.')
        else :
            await channel.send(content='HTTP Request Failed: Error {}'.format(req.status_code))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This is the data I should be getting from the API: (Test IP)

```
{  
   "as":"AS15169 Google LLC",
   "city":"Mountain View",
   "country":"United States",
   "countryCode":"US",
   "isp":"Google",
   "lat":37.4192,
   "lon":-122.0574,
   "org":"Google",
   "query":"74.125.224.72",
   "region":"CA",
   "regionName":"California",
   "status":"success",
   "timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
   "zip":"94043"
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Can you post the entire traceback so it's clear which line is throwing the error?

Comment: I *think* your issue is here: `if resp.status.code`, that's not how you access Python dictionaries

Comment: You're right - That's the issue, but he is using requests incorrectly. Resp returns a dictionary and you then search for `status` which doesn't exist. The correct usage would be `status_code` which was pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your usage of `resp.status.code`.

When using the Python requests module, you should use `resp.status_code` instead. It gets a dictionary as the response, and looks for `status` instead of `status_code`.

Examining your code now after the response to my answer and it seems you are looking for a `status_code` on `json.loads`.

Please try: `req.status_code` instead as that way you are looking for `status_code` on the actual request.

Comment: I think they will get the same error for `resp.status_code`, because they have used `json.loads` on the response.  I think you are thinking of `req.status_code`

Comment: Hmm, they don't need to be using `json.loads()`. If you're working with an API which returns JSON format, then you should use `json.loads(request.contents)` as only the content of the API page will contain JSON. Okay, that's what he did, I see what you mean. He should be doing `req.status_code` so.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the job. Will accept as answer in 4 mins when i'm able to.

Comment: No problem at all.